# spring boot version change and jakarta dependency

Tags: configuration, version-control, dependencies, rebuild

after changing spring boot vesrion from 2.7.2 to 3.0.2 intallij and made changess in file as from javax to jakarta and when trying to run the apllication the message is getting like Process finished with exit code 1 and not able to run the application getting error in main file

need some sujestions how i can resolve this issue and i tried Check your dependencies,Check your deployment,Check the classpath,Library conflicts,Clean and rebuild still getting issue not able to resolve

Comment: Please add the detailed error message you are seeing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.